# MySQL store time conditions

Tags: mysql, structure, duration

I am currently working on a platform where I would like to offer some rentals.

I want to store all possible rental types in the database, so I do not need to take care of logic in code.

Basically I want to offer following rental-times:

- 1 day
- 7 days
- 5 days / need to be weekdays ( which is monday to
  friday )
- 2 days / weekend ( needs to be saturday till sunday )
- 1 month / which will be from e.g. 14 of some month till 13th of following month

For the time of days I thought of storing data in minutes, this is easy to figure out.

If there is a weekday condition I thought of using the DAYOFWEEK Indexes, so I could define for 5 days, the first day of rental needs to have index 2 which is Monday, for weekend I could define that the day of rental needs to have index 6, which is Saturday.

```
rental_type_id | rental_time_in_minutes | rental_label | rental_start_day_indexes
```

1 day  would be like

```
1 | 1440 | 1 day | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

7 days

```
2 | 10080 | 7 days | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

5 days

```
3 | 7200 | Weekdays | 2,3,4,5,6
```

etc.

Is this a way to go for, or should I store the rental time just in days?

Any help, advice, critics or cheers are helpful!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you use this, storing rental time in minutes could cause issues around DST where you have 23 or 25 hours in a day.

Also storing the indices as comma-separated lists will cause you problems. I would make a mapping table. That column is not in normal form and will be tough to query.

I would honestly just make different tables for the different durations.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the durations in seconds. Because it makes the whole thing easier to query and more felxible. Lets say you have those rental durations. Table durations:

```
d_id  type     duration
1     1 day       01
2     3 days      03
3     7 days      07
```

I would suggest that you use normal timestamps for the rentals. I would store the start and end timestamp. Lets say you have the following table.

In this example I'm using days instead of a timestamp just to make it easier to show. Let's say today is day 3. Table rentals:

```
customer  start   end
Bob         02      05
Joe         10      11
Ian         03      04
```

Let's say you want to want to get all the currently active rentals (Bob & Ian). You can fetch it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `rentals` WHERE `start`<3 AND 3<`end`
```

You can find all which of rental type "1 day" (Ian) by using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `rentals`,`durations` WHERE `end`-`start`=`duration` and `d_id`=1
```

The advantage of using timestamps is that you can very precisely set the rental start and end time. You can check how many hours and minutes the customer is too late with giving the object back. Then you can easily calculate the exact additional fees.

Comment: Hey thx for this good example of storing the time-data. in my case i would have to add the suggested mapping table of Aaron to have an additional checkup whether the day, the person wants to rent is allowed ( or a different price model ). The Use case of "booking" the rental is a little more complex than just days. There also exist conditions like rental duration = 2 days, but the start-day has to be saturday, so the rental is just on weekend. Thanks so far!